# Show tex section list in vim

Tags: vim, tex

I like to use vim for tex file editing.

My document is lengthy, so I hope to show a list of section or subsection and navigate by just typing enter on the section name.

Please let me know some good plug-in or setting.

I know [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/images/taglist_xp_cmd.gif) plug-in shows a method list when editing Java source code, but it does not work for tex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the built-in `:global` command:

```
:g/\\.*section{/#
```

and, possibly, a simple custom mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :g/\\.*section{/#<CR>:
```

type a line number followed by `<CR>` to jump to the desired line.

Answer (score 1):

I found [latex-box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) has the feature what I really want.

Answer (score 1):

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ptrv/4576213).  Save it as a file `$HOME/.ctags` on UNIX or `$HOME/ctags.cnf` on Windows.  It allows `ctags` to make references to everything interesting in LaTeX files.